# Python: Bit test against defined constants

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I'm writing a FUSE client, using `python-fuse`.

One of the functions that needs writing, mimics the Python `os.open()` function, and I need to test the flags argument.

It's easy to create a such an argument, by using the bitwise OR, to combine the [os.O_*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=os.fstat#open-flag-constants) constants.

But I can't figure out how to test if specific ones are set.

have seen

```
if flags | os.O_APPEND:
     ...
```

in the xmp.py example, which can't figure if that's right. Is it testing if the APPEND flags is set in flag? Ignores if any the other flags are set?

I trying

```
if not (flags | os.O_RDONLY):
```

and it doesn't seem to work.

Definitely a python noob.

Comment: this example doesn't work and is misleading. it should be &, so that the O_APPEND flag acts as a mask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test by masking with `&`:

```
if flags & os.O_APPEND:
```

`|` is used to *combine* flags, use `&` (bitwise AND) to test if a flag is set. The `if flags | os.O_APPEND` line is most likely an error in the `xmp.py` example, it is *always* going to be `True`.

Demo:

```
>>> import os
>>> 0 & os.O_APPEND
0
>>> os.O_APPEND & os.O_APPEND
8
>>> (os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREAT) & os.O_APPEND
0
>>> (os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREAT | os.O_APPEND) & os.O_APPEND
8
```

Because numeric 0 is false and any other numeric value is true, `8` is seen as true.

Note that `os.O_RDONLY` is `0`; it is the equivalent of not having set *any* flags. You can test for that explicitly (`if not flags` or `if flags == os.O_RDONLY`), or infer it from tests for the other flags.

Comment: The only problem with this is that `os.O_RDONLY` is `0` so `&`-ing it will always be false. That one should be made a special case.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez: Right, because that is the equivalent of not having specified any flags at all.

Comment: @Markijn: Thanks, that totally makes sense! Knew it had to be something simple! Next silly question... I suppose `if (flags & os.O_APPEND) == 0:` is probably a better of inverting the test?

Comment: No, just test for `if flags & os.O_APPEND` or `if not flags & os.O_APPEND` and rely on the boolean context for `0` and `not 0`.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez - Ah, that will probably why my many experiments with trying to test O_RDONLY has been failing! (I thought had tried & but got confused with everything tried)

Comment: Yes. Think all set now. Use & to test. And cant directly os.O_RDONLY (cos it 0 internaly) - so instead test presense of write flag(s) rather than testing readony (to imply no write).